# Routing traffic as transit. WinTun driver. Network Interface/Adapter

Tags: networking, routing, network-adapter

I want to all traffic pass via WinTun adapter (ip:`10.6.7.7` mask:`255.255.255.0`) and after pass through ethernet (ip:`192.168.1.14` mask:`255.255.255.0`). I must to be like filter adapter to block STUN packets.

I have tried set `route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 metric 1 if 22` with `22` is WinTun adapter ID.

All traffic went through adapter, but don't go through ethernet and I have not internet. I think, I should change something in my user-space app, but what?

[image]

[image: my route table]

What I should do?

Comment: are your nic DNS server addresses set to the IP of a DNS server available from the remote network? are you certain that the remote VPN endpoint is configured to forward traffic? what is the specific error you get in the browser when you fail to connect to a site? are you able to resolve addresses using nslookup?

Comment: After wintun adapter received packets, ethernet don't receive packets. Wintun just receive and release packets does not change anything.

Comment: i posted browser error image on question.

Comment: I don't use vpn server for now. I want to route traffic through adapter Wintun.  And block some packets and release packets without change their.

Comment: ok whatever the remote tunnel end point is, is it configured to forward to its network?

Comment: I didn't get it, but WinTun IPv4 Connectivity: No network access.  I have post my route table.

Comment: ok so a tunnel is a point-to-point thing by nature. you are connecting two computers together. if you want to connect your PC to another computer, and use that computer's network (not just send data to the remote system), then that remote computer has to be configured to pass traffic on to the networks its is connected to. in linux you do that with command like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (exact command varies by distro). you may also have to configure IP tables for NAT so the two networks can talk together. so is the remote computer set up to forward your traffic on its network?